# Using two last names after marriage to reduce document updates

Tags: marriage, name

If after marriage, I take both my and my spouses last names, would I need to update documents such as my passport and driver's license?

For example,

```
John Apple  ==> John Apple Pear
Jane Pear   ==> Jane Apple Pear
```

The goal would be to have matching last names to avoid problems with things like hospital visitations, child pickups, etc. where last names are often used to verify relationships.

But at the same time, having to reconfigure all our legal documents would be rather painful. Not to mention gaining access to old bank accounts and things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If after marriage, I take both my and my spouses last names, would I
>   need to update documents such as my passport and driver's license?

Yes. I have done this (my premarital name was Willeke and my wife's was Oh) and you do need to update your documents if you do.